# How to make command which is trashing the document by spaces

Tags: spacing

I need to write command `\setToOldWidth` which makes operations on strings and counters and lengths.

Unfortunately the command as it is below inputs many spaces into the text not sure why probably due to string manipulation operations. How to make it completely silent but still to properly set the value of the length?

I can't use xstring as it's conflicting with other things in my very old class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{getOldWidthExtendedSettingsPos}
\newcounter{getOldWidthOldWidthPos}
\newcounter{getOldWidthOldOptionLength}

\newcommand{\setToOldWidth}[2]{%
    \whereisword[q]{#2}{Extended~Settings}%
    \setcounter{getOldWidthExtendedSettingsPos}{\theresult}%
%    
    \whereisword[q]{#2}{Old~Width=}%
    \setcounter{getOldWidthOldWidthPos}{\theresult}%
%
    \stringlength[q]{#2}%
    \setcounter{getOldWidthOldOptionLength}{\theresult}%
%    
    \ifnum\thegetOldWidthExtendedSettingsPos>0%
        \ifnum\thegetOldWidthOldWidthPos>0%
            \addtocounter{getOldWidthOldWidthPos}{10}%
            \substring[e]{#2}{\thegetOldWidthOldWidthPos}{\thegetOldWidthOldOptionLength}%
            \settowidth{#1}{\thestring}%
        \else%
            \settowidth{#1}{#2}%
        \fi%
    \else%
        \settowidth{#1}{#2}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\testwidth}

Test\setToOldWidth{\testwidth}{Extended Settings,Picture Width=120mm,Old Width=AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXZ}next part

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please rewrite your question such that others can understand what exactly it is you want to do here.

Comment: @daleif rephrased

Comment: It is still not clear what the end goal is. What exactly is `perations on strings and counters and lengths.`?

Comment: you should leave a space after the `0` in the `\ifnum` comparisons, like this `\ifnum\thegetOldWidthExtendedSettingsPos>0 %` and `\ifnum\thegetOldWidthOldWidthPos>0 %`.

Comment: @daleif if there is `Old Width=` in #2 extract the rest of the string there is use it as an argyment to `\settowidth` otherwise takes the whole #2 and use it as the argument for `\settowidth`

Comment: also there is a missing comment sign `\substring[e]{#2}{\thegetOldWidthOldWidthPos}{\thegetOldWidthOldOptionLength}%`

Comment: @daleif this command `\whereisword[q]{#2}{Extended~Settings}%` produces unnecessary empty spaces into the code.

Comment: @RuixiZhang you right the missing comment sign changes nothing the problem is with operations `\whereisword` they are producing unecessary empty spaces

Comment: glad that you found the problem. `:)`

Comment: It would be better if you explain what's the job you expect the macros do.

Comment: @RuixiZhang thanks for your help but you didn't find the problem. It was not causing the issue calling `\whereisword` produes the problem and I don't know how to isolate it I need something like `\whereisword > /dev/null` ;)

Comment: @egreg the job looks for expressions  `Extended Settings` and `Old Width=` in the passed argument #2. If they both presented it makes the substring from #2 starting from the character after `Old Width=` to the end. The result of that substring is used for `\settowidth{#1}{<substring>}`.  If there are not expressions like these it takes the entire #2 and use as value for `\settowidth{#1}{#2}`

Comment: @Luman75 Please, add a *complete* specification to your question, possibly with a few example of calls. I think there are better ways to accomplish the task.

Comment: I didn't claim to solve your original question. Rather, I pointed out several potential problems within your code. The `\ifnum` comparison is one such problem. As egreg said in the answer, without the space after the `0` things can get wrong very easily. I also simply pointed out one line that is missing a comment sign. In summary, I just *commented* some problems you might want to fix, but didn't write an *answer* to solve your original question. I hope this explain my intention for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unwanted space is in `stringstrings`:

```
940   \else
941     \if \thestring#3\global\matchingchartrue\else\global\matchingcharfalse\fi
942   \fi}
943 \?}
```

The endline in line 942 is unprotected.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\testmatchingchar}{ \?}{\?}{}{}
```

fixes the issue. Report it.

[image]

However you should remove your `%` at the end of the lines

```latex
    \ifnum\thegetOldWidthExtendedSettingsPos>0
        \ifnum\thegetOldWidthOldWidthPos>0
```

Those `%` would cause untimely expansion of the following tokens, in particular the first one.

### How did I find the rogue space?

I added `\tracingmacros=1 \tracingcommands=1` before the call of the macro and compiled. Then I looked in the log file for `blank space` and found several of them at

```latex
\matchingcharfalse ->\let \ifmatchingchar \iffalse
{end-group character }}
{horizontal mode: blank space  }
```

So I looked in `stringstring.sty` for `\matchingcharfalse` and it only appears in the replacement text of `\testmatchingchar`. Spotting the unprotected endline was easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. Just to understand your magic solution what you are patching?

Comment: The macro ends up with an unwanted space before the final `\?`; the patch looks for the combination `<space>\?` and replaces it with `\?`. Note that I added a recommendation about your own code.